# Download not getting executed after button press

Tags: android

I am testing an app that downloads a file on button click. But when the button is clicked nothing happens. The dialog box appears and gets disappeared in a fraction of a second. Don't know what is wrong
Here is my code

*mainactivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0; 
private Button startBtn;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton);

    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                startDownload();
            }

        });
}

private void startDownload()
{ 
String url = "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/114/298125983_0e4bf66782_b.jpg";
new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url); 
} 
@Override protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS: mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false); 
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
        default: return null; 
        } 
        }
        class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{ 
@Override protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute(); 
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        } 
        @Override protected String doInBackground(String... aurl)
    { 
    int count; 
    try
        { 
        URL url = new URL(aurl[0]); 
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection(); conexion.connect(); 
        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/some_photo_from_gdansk_poland.jpg");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0; while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1)
            {
                total += count;
                publishProgress("" + (int)((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return null;
    } protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress)
    {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", progress[0]);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    } @Override protected void onPostExecute(String unused)
    {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }
    }
 }
```

**Android manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: is it showing something.. `Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);`

Comment: try to use `InputStream input = conexion.getInputStream()` instead of `InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());`.

Comment: @sourabhbans Tried it but the same issue, thanks for taking interest

Comment: ok.. now debug it or print the error in ` catch (Exception e)
        {// here
        }`

Comment: @sourabhbans Ran the debugger but no problem

Comment: did you check the file in sdcard?

Comment: @sourabhbans Yeah checked it. It's not there. Do you know any other better way to add download feature in the app

Comment: see the working code in answer.

Comment: and your code working fine also... are you trying it on emulator ?

Comment: @sourabhbans Yeah tried it . don't know what is the problem with the code

Comment: use the sdcard path as.. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/test_image.jpg"` and check the internet connection too..

Comment: @sourabhbans Tried it but again same. The Internet connection is on otherwise how will I post  the comments

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        Context context;
        String downloadUrl;
        // shared preferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        int state;

        public DownloadFileAsync(Context context, String downloadUrl) {
            this.context = context;
            this.downloadUrl = downloadUrl;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait......");
                        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                        progressDialog.setMax(100);
                        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                        progressDialog.show();
                    }
                });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(downloadUrl.toString());
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
                if (lenghtOfFile > 0) {
                    // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                    // Output stream to write file
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                                    + "/data.jpg");
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                    long total = 0;
                    Log.d("lenghtOfFile", "---" + lenghtOfFile);
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        // writing data to file
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                        // publishing the progress. After this onProgressUpdate
                        // will be called
                        publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    }

                    // flushing output
                    output.flush();

                    // closing streams
                    output.close();

                    input.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    }
```

on click of button call it like below

```
new DownloadFileAsync(MainActivity.this, url).execute();
```

it works and add the following permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: try with this 
// input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
   InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

Comment: Tried it but the same issue

Comment: k check it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

here is the working code..

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("Starting : ", "Starting...");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.status)).setText("Starting...");  



        // execute this when the downloader must be fired
        final getAppInfo downloadTask = new getAppInfo();
        downloadTask.execute("http://farm1.static.flickr.com/114/298125983_0e4bf66782_b.jpg");



  }





       private class getAppInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            /** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
              * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
            ProgressDialog dialog;


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                     dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                     dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                     dialog.setMessage("Loading");
                     dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                     dialog.setCancelable(false);   
                     dialog.setMax(100);
                     dialog.setProgress(100);
                     dialog.show();
                }



            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {                       
                InputStream input = null;
                OutputStream output = null;
                HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
                    connection.connect();


                    String length = connection.getHeaderField("Content-length");
                    Log.e("fileLength : ",""+length);

                    // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
                    // instead of the file
                    if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                                + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
                    }

                    // this will be useful to display download percentage
                    // might be -1: server did not report the length
                    int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                    Log.e("fileLength : ",""+fileLength);

                    // download the file
                    input = connection.getInputStream();

//                   final String resultt = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(input, "UTF-8");
//                   Log.e("Response : ",""+resultt);

                    output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/testsql.jpg");

                    byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        // allow canceling with back button
                        if (isCancelled()) {
                            input.close();
                            return null;
                        }
                        total += count;
                        // publishing the progress....
                        if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                            publishProgress(""+(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("exception : ",""+e.getMessage());
                    return e.toString();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (output != null)
                            output.close();
                        if (input != null)
                            input.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }

                    if (connection != null)
                        connection.disconnect();
                }
                return null;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
                Log.v("count",progress[0]);
                dialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
           }

            /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
              * the result from doInBackground() */
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {    
                //dialog.setProgress(100);
                    if(dialog!=null) dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

}
```